# Tabs and menu background is dark in light theme

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I'm using the following theme:

```
<style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
</style>
```

I'm also using the old actiobar and not the new Toolbar.

However, it's still using the dark theme for:

- Tabs in a tabbed page are dark
- Any menus have a dark background

How do I fix this?

Comment: Its default that if your style is light your menu will be dark.

Comment: @Shvet So, how do I override?

Answer (score 0):

For menu you can use `actionOverflowMenuStyle` in your style to give background color. This is working in my app with `toolbar` and `Appcompat`. I havent tested it on other (conventional actionbar).

`<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/CMOptionsMenu</item>`

Where `CMOptionsMenu` is:

```
<style name="CMOptionsMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm using the old actionbar

Comment: if you have added `Appcompat`library you will get same parent style unless you just need to remove AppCompat from parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android ActionBar style generator:

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/